# Selected an option in edit view cakephp 3.0

Tags: select, cakephp-3.0

I am generating list within a form like the following code. But for updating view how can select the particular option according to the user. Suppose for this user's role is Customer. Then how can select this(Customer) option in CakePHP 3.

```
<?= $this->Form->create($user) ?>
<?php
        echo $this->Form->input('fullname');
        echo $this->Form->input('contact_no');
        ?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <?php echo $this->Form->select(
                'role',
                ['Customer', 'Staff', 'User'],
                ['title' => 'Select user type']
            ); ?>
        </div>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Comment: not very clear. Do you want the 'Customer' option to be already selected when the user visits the page according to his role?

Comment: @arilia ,  I want to select role option from select list according to user role.

Comment: the list should be already selected. If you print out `$user->role` what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did : (According that I have 2 tables : Users which belongsTo Roles)

In my UsersController, i added this following line :

```
$this->set('roles', $this->Users->Roles->find('list')->order('name'));
```

Then, you'll need to edit your view from

```
<div class="form-group">

    <?php echo $this->Form->select(
        'role',
        ['Customer', 'Staff', 'User'],
        ['title' => 'Select user type']
    ); ?>

</div>
```

to

```
<div class="form-group">

    <?= $this->Form->select(
            'role_id', 
            $roles, 
            ['id' => 'role-id', 'required' => true]
        ); 
    ?>

</div>
```